# Checking for a field error using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I've been trying to implement tests to check for field validation in forms. A check for specific field error messages was straightforward, but I've also tried a generic check to identify the parent element of a field for an error class. This however isn't working.

A field with an error has the following HTML;

```
<div class="field clearfix error ">
    <div class="error">
        <p>Please enter a value</p>
    </div>
    <label for="id_fromDate">
    <input id="id_fromDate" type="text" value="" name="fromDate">
</div>
```

So to check for an error I've got the following function;

```
def assertValidationFail(self, field_id):
    # Checks for a div.error sibling element
    el = self.find(field_id)
    try:
        error_el = el.find_element_by_xpath('../div[@class="error"]')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        error_el = None
    self.assertIsNotNone(error_el)
```

So `el` is the input field, but then the xpath always fails. I believed that `../` went up a level in the same way that command line navigation does - is this not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misunderstood your question earlier. You may try the following logic: find the parent `div`, then check if it contains class `error`, rather than find parent `div.error` and check `NoSuchElementException`.

Because `..` is the way to go upper level, `../div` means parent's children `div`.

```
// non-working code, only the logic
parent_div = el.find_element_by_xpath("..") # the parent div
self.assertTrue("error" in parent_div.get_attribute("class"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this way of doing it. But it seems grabbing the parent_div for the error only works on input fields. On multiple select boxes or radio button's the parent seems to be the option label & starting to do `./../../` type things is something I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using a relative xpath (based on an existing element), it needs to start with `./` like this:

```
el.find_element_by_xpath('./../div[@class="error"]')
```

Only after the `./` can you start specifying xpath nodes etc.